# Kotlin Coroutines - Jump function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to implement a "jump" inside my code using coroutines. I mean by imagining a Cartesian plane where X is the horizontal coordinate and Y is the vertical coordinate, starting from the point x = 0 and y = 0 through a coroutines (to no block main thread) I would like to get:

```
y= 0
y=  1
y=   2
y=    3
y=     4
y=      5
y=       6
y=      5
y=     4
y=    3
y=   2
y=  1
y= 0
```

I need to do this to update the new value every time.
I'm starting from an idea like this:

```
    fun jumpUp() {

    jumpPosition = 0

    repeat(5) {
        sleep(10)
        jumpPosition += 10
        coordinates[coordinates.x] = coordinates.y - jumpPosition
    }
    repeat(5) {
        sleep(30)
        coordinates[coordinates.x] = coordinates.y + jumpPosition
        jumpPosition -= 10
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to find a solution (maybe without coroutines)

Comment: Why do you need a coroutine? What is definition of `player.jump()` function?

Comment: I would to implement a "job" to update y coordinate. jump function do that. I can use handler to update y every 100 ms to do Y = 1, then 2, then 3 etc
I would like to do: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 ->5  and then ->4 -> 3 -> 2-> 1 -> 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve the problem. As I said, I wanted to use the coroutines to represent the jump in a 2D game because in doing so I just avoided blocking the thread and allowing the game to run smoothly. It was enough for me to use the repeat function and the coroutines like this:

I implemented the coroutines in build.gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6"
```

jump solution:

```
// Take a jump
fun jump() {
    jumpJob = coroutineScope.launch {
        repeat(6) {
            delay(GameParameters.instance.jumpMovementDuration.toLong() / 10)
            jumpPosition += GameParameters.instance.jumpHeight / 10
            coordinates[coordinates.x] = coordinates.y - jumpPosition
        }

        delay(GameParameters.instance.jumpStasisDuration.toLong())

        repeat(6) {
            delay(GameParameters.instance.jumpMovementDuration.toLong() / 10)
            coordinates[coordinates.x] = coordinates.y + jumpPosition
            jumpPosition -= GameParameters.instance.jumpHeight / 10
        }
    }
}
```